# Count the number of Cos and sine waves in a raw signal

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a score or a number which represents how many cos and sin waves can generate my signal. For example, if the signal is a sine wave this means it is 100% pure as it can be generated by only one sine signal, if it consists of two sine wave .. this means it is not pure wave and if it consists 100 sine waves it is really unpure and so on .... I tried FFT and FS but it didn't work ... Can anyone help me ??

Comment: Do these sine waves have frequencies that are integer multiples of each other?  i.e. are they harmonically-related?

Comment: My signal consists of random raw data, and to my knowledge each signal can be generated from a number of sine and cos waves with different amp, freq and phase .. but I was wondering how to do that.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use the fft() function followed by findpeaks(). There are other more nuanced ways to count components (e.g., [MUSIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_signal_classification), and [Pisarenko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisarenko_harmonic_decomposition)) if needed, but I'd start with just fft().

Comment: But FFT has a limitation as it range from -pi to pi , can I used it in normal signal or shall I used Fourier series?

Comment: Your signal is presumably sampled, so it should be bandlimited. Otherwise, you should be using a network analyzer or some other piece of hardware. At this point, if you want real help, you need to provide more details on what you have exactly and what your level of understanding is, because your concern doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I have a signal and I need to know how much is it sinosoidal, 100% means it is a pure sinusoidal and percentage will decrease while increasing the number of sin waves which construct the signal.

Comment: You've already stated that. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
x = s;
X = dct(x);
[XX,ind] = sort(abs(X),'descend');
i = 1;
while norm(X(ind(1:i)))/norm(X)<0.99
   i = i + 1;
end
Needed = i;
```

Comment: I don't get how this '*works perfectly*'!? Not even the simplest test case `t = linspace(0,10,100); s = sin(t);` works.

Comment: Some explanation or rationale behind how this works would be nice.  I don't understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: When I put a normal signal, the "needed" variable contains a small number of components  needed to reconstruct the signal. On the other hand, if I put a noisy signal the "needed" variable has a large number of components which shows that it needs a lot of components to reconstruct the signal. This is a perfect score which I can use.

Comment: @SMH - the `Needed` variable is only a single number which (looks like) the total number of components needed to represent the signal within a 1% error of the norm.  I also don't understand why the coefficients need to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

FFT will work.
You must process wave with Fourier Transform, then calculate the magnitude
**sqrt(real*real + image*image)**. Counting the peaks of result will provide you number of sinewaves with different frequency.

Comment: Is it better to use Fourier series or FFT as what I know that it has a limit from -pi to pi .. and shall we calculate the sqrt(real*real + image*image) for all the samples or what ?

Comment: fft_data = fft(sinwave, FFT_SIZE); FFT_SIZE must be power of 2, for example 4092. Yes, you should process an interesting fragment of your sinewave, though more samples you process in fft more time you wait for results.

Comment: but the point is that my signal is not a sine wave .. it is a raw data

Comment: that's it, you should pass your raw data to fft function. As long as algorithm can find repetitive patterns in your data, the result will be better. If it's just random data like signal noise, fft will propably return very low frequencies.

Comment: Thanks Jacek .. I just need to understand why we calculate sqrt(realreal + imageimage)  after calculating FFT and finally how to count the peaks?

Comment: There is no requirement that the FFT size be a power of 2. There are many different sizes for which fft is optimized and, moreover, it will still work with non-optimized sizes. Unless, you are doing realtime processing or calculating millions of fft's, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: fft gives you complex result. I'm not very good in theory, but complex numbers makes it possible to represent frequencies AND phases. That's why we must turn complex numbers into real numbers.